# Does Android have no protection against malicious public USB ports?

Tags: malware, android, physical, data-leakage

I was reading a [bunch](http://money.cnn.com/2017/02/15/technology/public-ports-charging-bad-stop/index.html) [of](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwi-gtCI-PzVAhWS8oMKHZ_qA0AQFgguMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.telegraph.co.uk%2Ftechnology%2F2016%2F05%2F27%2Fbeware-public-mobile-charging-points---your-phone-can-be-hacked%2F&usg=AFQjCNGij_NyOLbCUWKha3y8RqrXNLNAWw) [news articles](https://fossbytes.com/juice-jacking-public-ports-hacking/) which asked not to charge phone using public USB ports as they could be malicious.

According to the web pages, the USB wires carry data and power so they have a capacity to infect your phone or steal the data. Is there no protection in Android against it?

What about the option on Android phones to use a phone for just charging or transferring data when connected to computer?

Comment: Use an USB cable with no data lines, i.e. for charging only.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich that is definitely doable. I am wondering if there is a software based solution (Maybe a kernel module or something). There may very well not be and using a USB cable with no data lines could be the most feasible solution. I will not deny that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has this feature now.

Go into either
**Settings > System > About phone**
or
**Settings > About phone**.
Inside About phone tap on **Build number** about 7 times. Navigate back to Settings at the top of the screen and enter 'developer' into the Search View. From the search results you'll need to follow the **Developer options** link. Inside Developer options flip the switch at the top to **On** and then scroll down and tap **Select USB Configuration**. In the dialog select a configuration from the options, and you're all set. To help prevent attacks from malicious chargers you would generally set the configuration to **Charging**.

Comment: Does this always work? If it does, then yes. It does solve the problem

Comment: Yeah, it works every time. It can get annoying having to confirm each time you connect ADB.